# javascript cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript

This function is supposed to hide the patient note and show the next note (if they have another note)

```js
function nextNote(idno){
    document.getElementById(idno).style.display = 'none';
    var idno2 = parseInt(idno)+1;
    document.getElementById(idno2.toString()).style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('prevNote').label = parseInt(document.getElementById('prevNote').label) + 1;
    document.getElementById('nextNote').label = parseInt(document.getElementById('nextNote').label) + 1;
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at `"document.getElementById(idno).style.display = 'none';`

The element in question
`<li class="notes" label="1052" style="display: inline;" id="1">On: 5/17/2004 A real good Patient test</li>`

nextNote is being called by: `<input type="button" id="nextNote" class="notesbottombutton" value=">" label="1" onclick="nextNote(this.label);" />`

If I use the Chrome javascript console
`document.getElementById(1).style.display;` I get: `"inline"`

Note I will add checks to the function after I get it work such as if(document.getElementById(idno2.toString()) so that it doesn't do anything if there are no more notes to display, I am just trying to get the basic functionality first

Comment: There is no element in the DOM with ID of whatever value of `idno` that causes this error.

Comment: If you look at the element in question: `<li class="notes" label="1052" style="display: inline;" id="1">On: 5/17/2004 A real good Patient test</li>` and where nextNote is being called: `<input type="button" id="nextNote" class="notesbottombutton" value=">" label="1" onclick="nextNote(this.label);" />` It does exist...

Comment: Put a `console.log(idno)` in `nextNote()`, before the `gEBI` call. Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is your click handler:

```
nextNote(this.label);
```

`label` is not a property of HTML inputs. It's not even a valid attribute. To set the caption of an `input` with `type="button"`, you should use its `value` attribute and use `this.value` to access it.

If you're just using this attribute to attach data to the element and want to access the attribute, you should do it like this:

```
nextNote(this.getAttribute('label'));
```

But I'd recommended that you use a `data-` prefixed attribute instead, the standard way to attach data in HTML 5 (it's also backwards compatible):

```
<input data-label="foo" />

nextNote(this.getAttribute('data-label'));
```

Comment: How would I set that, as the buttons also change their label data to reflect the position of which note it is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

`this.label` refers to the label property on the element, but you are setting an attribute called label.  Change your onclick to:

```
onclick="nextNote(this.getAttribute('label'));"
```